# Does the group of permutation of n letter contains subgroup of order of all divisors of $n!$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S_{n}$ be the group of premutation of n letter $ {1,.....n} $ with order is $| S_{n}|=n!$

Consider $d(n!)$  the number of divisors of $n!$

The Lagrange theorem tells us that if 
$H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then the order Of $H$ divide the order of $G$ so if there is exist a subgroup of any group $G$ then the order that subgroup should be one of the divisors of |G| but the theorem does not guaranty that this subgroup exist

My question 
Does this subgroups exist in the  group $S_{n}$for all divisions of $n!$ ? If not, does there exist a group with this property?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking, but $S_5$ has order 120 and no subgroup of order 30.

Comment: Any finite abelian group has a subgroup of order $\,n\;$ for **any divisor** $\;n\;$ of its order...

Comment: Ancientmathematician the Lagrange theorem tells us that if H is a subgroup of G so it is ordered should divide of the order G .but it is done not  guaranty that this subgroup exist I ask if existsist for all divisor of n! In $S_{n}$

Comment: @DonAnonio he gives counter example

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. The question seems to me clear and motivated (at least in its current form).

Comment: Ancientmathematician has answered your first question ($S_5$ does not have subgroups of all orders that divide $5!$), and Don Antonio has answered your second question (there are lots of groups that have subgroups of all the orders allowed by Lagrange's theorem, namely all finite abelian groups).

Comment: @Andreas Blass i need example of of group that depende of n like $D_{n}$

Comment: @Abdo Considering that cyclic groups $C_n$ are abelian, Don Antonio has given you the examples you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the symmetric group $S_n$ for $n\geq 5$ does not have a subgroup of every order dividing $n!$. A group $G$ that has a subgroup of order $d$ for every $d$ such that $d\mid |G|$ is called a [CLT group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) (CLT stands for "converse of Lagrange's theorem.") The Wikipedia article gives the example that a [supersolvable group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersolvable_group) is always a CLT group, as are finite abelian groups. However, solvable groups need not be CLT groups, and CLT groups such as $S_4$ need not be supersolvable.

Any nonabelian simple group must not be a CLT group. Since these groups have even order and a subgroup of index $2$ is normal, these groups cannot have a subgroup of index $2$.

Comment: is there a CLT group of order n!

Comment: @Abdo Sure. Just pick an abelian group of that order.

Comment: the group $\mathbb{Z}/n!\mathbb{Z}$ .is that true

Comment: @Abdo Sure. Or $\prod_{i=2}^n{\mathbb Z/i\mathbb Z}$.